# Commercial Use of a Recorded Output of Speech Synthesis made via Web Speech API

Tags: webspeech-api

I know this is NOT the right forum, but I couldn't find a better one... It's a legal question intended for the MDN team members.

I use the Web Speech API via Chrome / Firefox to synthesize speech of my original text.
I record the output audio using some other software.

Do I own the copyrights to that recording? Can I sell the recorded audio file? Can I use it in my commercial YouTubes for instance?

It would seem to me - I am indeed the owner of the recording, as the speech api is given as one of the browser's services, which I can use to produce my own content. But - I would like to be sure.

The closest answer by Google I saw is here:
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2013Jul/0001.html
Which says the web speech api can be used for commercial. My specific question is about the recorded audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've asked a copyrights attorney - See full answer [here](http://ttsreader.com/blog/2017/05/10/copyright/).

Here's the summary:

1. You do own the copyrights.
2. Owning the copyrights does NOT necessarily grant permission for commercial use, as you might be bound to contractual obligations (as is the case for iOS voices for instance).

Answer (score 0):

E.g. if you create a document using Microsoft Word the contents might be copyright to Microsoft? (No!)

- Can you sell the file? (Yes)
- Can you use it in a Youtube vid? (Yes)