# Is there any possible solution to get mp3 of text I get blob but not play able

Tags: javascript, get, mp3, text-to-speech

Is there any possible solution to get mp3 of text I get blob but not play able

```
text =  document.getElementById("text");
            voice = document.getElementById("Svoice");
            action = document.getElementById("action");

        function texttospeech(text){
            let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
            items = [];
            let record = speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            
            items.push(record);
            var blob = new Blob(items, {type:'audio/mp3'});
            aud.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }

        action.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (text.value !== ""){
                texttospeech(text.value);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me without node.js or any other library only javascript please

Comment: You have a blob? Is it base-64 encoded?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

You can't record speech synthesis output in the browser.

---

The W3C draft report for the Web Speech API does not include methods for accessing [speech synthesis](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#tts-section) output, and [`SpeechSynthesis.speak(speech)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak) returns `undefined`,  not data to create a blob from.

Browser software implementing the speech synthesizer component of the API may in fact be calling the O/S to synthesize the speech rather than producing any kind of audio stream itself.

Most speech synthesis output heard on YouTube is likely being captured by the video recording/screen capture software used to record the video.  Please research further to determine what might suite you best - I am not offering recommendations other than to include "Xbox Gamebar App" and "VLC" in your searches if they don't turn up by themselves.

This [related question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419958/5217142) covers interesting information about copyright and potential limitations on commercial use of recorded speech synthesis output imposed by some manufacturers.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - you even get a badge. Although you hoped to be able to record speech synthesis in a browser,  accepting this answer will close off the post for people or bots searching for unsolved questions.